# Swap slots after app full initialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-deployment-slots

Is there a way to swap slots only after app full initialization? I have a web app on Azure and swapping slots process is pretty fast, but after that, the application had to do the initialization which in my app takes a few minutes, since there are some heavy tasks.

Swapping slots for me at this moment is not worthing because of this.

I want to use swap slots to reduce downtime, we have a frequently update schedule, since my clients work 24 hr/day, even on the weekends.

I may optimize this initialization process, but not right now... So I need a way to swap after this initialization, this will reduce my downtime to the time spent swapping the slots which take a few seconds redirecting all current requests.

I was thinking of to start a job after initialization and prompt Azure to do the swapping, but i couldn't find a way to do that. Is this bad? There's a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, there's already a powershell command and azure cli:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/switch-azurewebsiteslot?view=azuresmps-4.0.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest